# how to get surrounding objects in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I have been trying to remake connect 4 in p5js as a little  learning project but i cant get the winning mechanic where having 4 connected makes you win the game. i am using a method that checks every surrounding position in the grid array and then if that one has the same color as the peice thats checking then it adds 1 in the direction the piece is plus the amount that piee has in that direction.`

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(350, 300);
  setBoard();
}

class Slot {
  constructor(x, y, scale, color){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.scale = scale;
    this.color = color;
    this.connectedBlocksX = 0;
    this.connectedBlocksY = 0;
    this.connectedBlocksXY = 0;
    this.connectedBlocksYX = 0;
    this.isFilled = false;
  }
  
  checkWin(x, y){
      if(grid[y][x].color != "gray"){
      if(y != 5 && x != 6 && grid[y+1][x+1].color == grid[y][x].color){
        grid[y][x].connectedBlocksXY += 1 + grid[y+1][x+1].connectedBlocksXY;
      }
      if(y != 0 && x != 6 && grid[y-1][x+1].color == grid[y][x].color){
        grid[y][x].connectedBlocksYX += 1 + grid[y-1][x+1].connectedBlocksYX;
      }
      if(y != 5 && x != 0 && grid[y+1][x-1].color == grid[y][x].color){
        grid[y][x].connectedBlocksYX+= 1 + grid[y+1][x-1].connectedBlocksYX;
      }
      if(y != 0 && x != 0 && grid[y-1][x-1].color == grid[y][x].color){
        grid[y][x].connectedBlocksXY += 1 + grid[y-1][x-1].connectedBlocksXY;
      }
      if(x != 6 && grid[y][x+1].color == grid[y][x].color){
        grid[y][x].connectedBlocksX+= 1 + grid[y][x+1].connectedBlocksX;
      }
      if(x != 0 && grid[y][x-1].color == grid[y][x].color){
        grid[y][x].connectedBlocksX+= 1 + grid[y][x-1].connectedBlocksX;
      }
      if(y != 5 && grid[y+1][x].color == grid[y][x].color){
        grid[y][x].connectedBlocksY+= 1 + grid[y+1][x].connectedBlocksY;
      }
      if(y != 0 && grid[y-1][x].color == grid[y][x].color){
        grid[y][x].connectedBlocksY += 1 + grid[y-1][x].connectedBlocksY;
      }
      
      if(grid[y][x].connectedBlocksY >= 3|| grid[y][x].connectedBlocksX >= 3 || grid[y][x].connectedBlocksYX >= 3 || grid[y][x].connectedBlocksXY >= 3){
        if(grid[y][x].color != "gray"){
          winner = grid[y][x].color;
        }
      }
    }
}
  
  draw(){
    fill(this.color);
    ellipseMode(CORNER);
    ellipse(this.x,this.y,this.scale, this.scale);
  }
  
  drop(){
    if(grid[0][(this.x - 5)/50].isFilled == false){
      if((this.y - 5)/50 != 0 && this.isFilled == true && grid[0][(this.x - 5)/50].isFilled == false){
        grid[(this.y - 5)/50 - 1][(this.x - 5)/50].drop();
        this.checkWin((this.x - 5)/50, (this.y - 5)/50 - 1);
      }
      else if((this.y - 5)/50 != 5){
        if(grid[(this.y - 5)/50 + 1][(this.x - 5)/50].isFilled == true && this.isFilled == false){
          if(turn == 0){
            turn = 1;
          }
          else{
            turn = 0;
          }
          this.checkWin((this.x - 5)/50, (this.y - 5)/50);
          this.isFilled = true;
          if(turn == 0){
            this.color = "red"
          }
          else{
            this.color = "yellow";
          }
        }
        else{
            grid[(this.y - 5)/50 + 1][(this.x - 5)/50].drop();
          this.checkWin((this.x - 5)/50, (this.y - 5)/50 + 1);
          }
        }
        else if(this.isFilled == false){
          if(turn == 0){
            turn = 1;
          }
          else{
            turn = 0;
          }
          this.checkWin((this.x - 5)/50, (this.y - 5)/50);
          this.isFilled = true;
          if(turn == 0){
            this.color = "red"
          }
          else{
            this.color = "yellow";
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
  }

const offset = 5;
var winner = null;
var turn = 0;
var rows = 6;
var cols = 7;
var grid = [];
grid[0] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
grid[1] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
grid[2] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
grid[3] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
grid[4] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
grid[5] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

function draw() {
  background("blue");
  for(var y = 0; y < rows; y++){
    for(var x = 0; x < cols; x++){
      grid[y][x].draw();
    }
  }
  if(winner != null){
    fill("black");
    textSize(50);
    text(winner + " Won!", 0, 290);
  }
}

function setBoard(){
  for(var y = 0; y < rows; y++){
    for(var x = 0; x < cols; x++){
      grid[y][x] = new Slot(x * 50 + offset, y * 50 + offset, 40, "gray");
    }
  }
}

function mousePressed(){
  for(var y = 0; y < rows; y++){
    for(var x = 0; x < cols; x++){
      if(mouseX >= grid[y][x].x && mouseX <= grid[y][x].x + grid[y][x].scale && mouseY >= grid[y][x].y && mouseY <= grid[y][x].y + grid[y][x].scale){
        grid[y][x].drop();
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean, I use this function I found long ago. Just put in the 2d array and the x and y position of the object you are trying to find the neighbors of. It will return the neighbors in a separate array.

```
function neighbors(arr, m, n) {
 let v = [[0, 1],[1, 0],[0, -1],[-1, 0]]
 return v.filter(([h, j]) => h + m >= 0 && h + m < arr.length && j + n >= 0 && j + n < arr[0].length)
 .map(([h, j]) => arr[h + m][j + n])

}
```

You can also increase the range if you'd like, this can be done in the v array using this:

```
function neighbors(arr, m, n, radius) {
let v = [];
for(x = -radius; x <= radius; x ++){
    for(y = -radius; y <= radius; y ++){
        if(x == 0 && y == 0){}else{
        v.push([x,y])
  }

    }
}


return v.filter(([h, j]) => h + m >= 0 && h + m < arr.length && j + n >= 0 && j + n < arr[0].length)
  .map(([h, j]) => arr[h + m][j + n])

}
```

Edit: I hope this explains:

```
let scale = 100;

let array2d = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    background(0);
    
    for(x = 0; x < width / scale; x ++){
        array2d[x]=  [];
        for(y = 0; y < height / scale; y ++){
            array2d[x][y] = new Point(x,y,0);
        }
    }

    
    print(array2d)
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    for(x = 0; x < array2d.length; x ++){
        for(y = 0; y < array2d[x].length; y ++){
            array2d[x][y].display();
        }
    }
}

class Point{
    constructor(x,y,color){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
        
    }
    display(){
        fill(this.color);
        stroke(100);
        rect(x * scale,y * scale,scale)
    }
}

function neighbors(arr, m, n, radius) {
let v = [];
for(x = -radius; x <= radius; x ++){
    for(y = -radius; y <= radius; y ++){
        if(x == 0 && y == 0){}else{
        v.push([x,y])
  }

    }
    
}
return v.filter(([h, j]) => h + m >= 0 && h + m < arr.length && j + n >= 0 && j + n < arr[0].length)
  .map(([h, j]) => arr[h + m][j + n])

}

function mousePressed(){
    let nei = neighbors(array2d,round(mouseX / scale - 0.5),round(mouseY / scale - 0.5),1);
    print(nei)
     for(i = 0; i < nei.length; i ++){
         nei[i].color = 255;
     }
}
```

Comment: how would i change it to look 3 in each direction?

Comment: how do i use this to change a value in the object?

Comment: i tried it and its a lot smaller than the original array

Comment: are you referring to array2d?

Comment: Yea and it works for all sizes, just input a radius for the last number.